# CSV separator is present in one of the value. How to ignore/handle such csv file?

Tags: java, csv, csvreader

I'm getting CSV file from external system. CSV is separated using `;` but one of the record has value with `;`

e.g:

```
name;age;address  
ab:20;12345  
s;m;30;12345  
xy;22;12345
```

How can I consider `s;m` as single value?
I'm using `DataFrame` of `Joinery` to read file and convert it to  `DataFrame` to ease further operations:

`Dataframe abc = DataFrame.readCsv(inputStream,";","", Boolean.TRUE);`

Comment: That is going to have to be fixed on the output side as whatever is doing that is not doing the necessary quoting/escaping to deal with the embedded separator/delimiter. Another option would be to change(on output) the separator to something like `|` assuming that does not appear in the data anywhere.